# CSS flexbox two columns

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I am trying to make a pure HTML/CSS site using flex box,  using an image that takes up 50% of the left, a text box that takes up 50% of the right, and the footer takes up 100% of the width below them(I'll want to add a navigation later, maybe a hamburger menu, not relevant to this issues atm) , while making them responsive to devices of different sizes. *I want the image and right text box to wrap into a column(img on top of text box) on smaller devices

[image]

Problems I am running in to are, setting the image to max-width or max-height 100%  makes it larger than the div container it in is, the image is not filling the box fully, (I want to keep the image proportionate to original size)

As you can see below, the image is not taking up 100% of the container, the below CSS is not the only CSS I've been experimenting with. But I have been looking at other articles I've found on stackoverflow etc, but nothing is looking for quite the same issue;

```
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  display:block
  }

img {
  // width:auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  // overflow: none;
  // position: absolute;
 height: 400px;
 // max-width: 100%;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 border: 1px solid green;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.container > * {
  padding: 0px;
  flex: 1 100%; }

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .content {
    flex: 1 0;
    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Please post enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You need to post your HTML code as well for us to help solve the problem

Comment: please create a code snippet ore add a jsfidlle link. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check below example. it's maybe helps you.

```css
  *, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #212529;
  }
  img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
  }
  .content {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
  }
  .content .col {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
  }
  .footer {
    background: #eee;
    height: 100px;
  }
  @media(max-width: 767px){
    .content .col {
      -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
      flex: 0 0 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <main>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="col left">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/994517/pexels-photo-994517.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" title="" alt=""/>
          </div>
          <div class="col right">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>

    <footer>
      <div class="footer"></div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!

What does this perform though?;

*, ::after, ::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }